Can LUKS2 root partition encryption with cryptsetup be done on an already fully running OS?
The Arch Linux wiki has some guide to first unmount and then shrink the partition before reencryption. but then it has a header saying:

This article or section needs expansion.
Reason: cryptsetup 2.2 using LUKS2 (with a 16 MiB header) supports online
encryption/decryption/reencryption.

Does that mean I can skip the unmount and resize steps, and just run the reencrypt command when the OS is still running on that partition?

While cryptsetup supports online re-encryption, this is only for devices that are already using LUKS2.
Maybe your volume key or entire header leaked, and you need a new one. Or you just don't like the old encryption settings and want to switch to a different encryption algorithm. That's when you re-encrypt all data with new keys. And with cryptsetup reencrypt it's done online, in the background.
Now, cryptsetup reencrypt --new can encrypt previously unencrypted devices. But this doesn't happen online. cryptsetup can't switch a mounted /dev/sdx3 to /dev/mapper/cryptsdx3 online. The kernel itself does not support changing devices like that.
If you try it anyway, you should see an error:
# cryptsetup reencrypt … /dev/sdx3
Failed to open /dev/sdx3 in exclusive mode (already mapped or mounted).
Failed to initialize LUKS2 reencryption in metadata.

(For some reason, this error only appears after it had you confirm and enter a passphrase and everything.)
So, you still have to unmount and resize.

However, once the re-encryption process is started, you can use the filesystem and let the re-encryption continue in the background. Basically you just kick-start the process and go online from there. You don't have to wait around and twiddle your thumbs until it's done.
For this purpose, cryptsetup reencrypt uses the --init-only option.
Example:
!!! umount and shrink by 32M first !!!

# cryptsetup reencrypt --new --reduce-device-size=32M --init-only /dev/sdx3

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on LUKS2-temp-f5ba670b-092c-4634-b6bc-63d1796434fd.new irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES
Enter passphrase for LUKS2-temp-f5ba670b-092c-4634-b6bc-63d1796434fd.new:
Verify passphrase:

With --init-only, at this point only the header is written. /dev/sdx3 is a LUKS2 device now, even though nothing is actually encrypted yet. But you can already open and mount it like any other LUKS device.
# cryptsetup open /dev/sdx3 cryptsdx3
# mount /dev/mapper/cryptsdx3 /mnt/somewhere

Once it's mounted, resume online reencrypt:
# cryptsetup reencrypt --resume-only /dev/sdx3

WARNING!
========
Device /dev/sdx3 is already in LUKS2 reencryption. Do you wish to resume previously initialised operation?

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdx3:
Progress:  56.1%, ETA 00m32s,    5 GiB written, speed 254.8 MiB/s

And with any luck, it will just work without corrupting anything.
(You should still have a backup.)
PS: --resume-only is optional. But the messages for resuming and starting new encryption look very similar, so it's easy to make mistakes. Whenever cryptsetup asks you to type YES, read twice to make sure what you're agreeing to.

Thanks! How do you umount when OS is running there though? Do I first need to boot into live USB for this with --init-only, and then reboot and resume online?

Yeah, that's the neat part… you don't umount the running OS rootfs. You'd have to do it in a live / rescue system. And then it has to be capable of opening a LUKS device on reboot. In ArchLinux it's basically arch-chroot then edit mkinitcpio.conf, and grub.cfg to add encrypt parameters. The wiki should help you with these things.
